# Extra audience lyrics in a K-Pop song?

Tags: lyrics, k-pop

We've been to Japan a couple of months ago and happened to catch a performance of a Korean group, [Snuper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snuper).

It is interesting that the audience takes part in the show, and is singling between the lines, as can be seen in this fan video, starting at 2:08 and [2:31](https://youtu.be/eZsIWW6Q7fk?t=2m31s):

https://youtu.be/eZsIWW6Q7fk?t=2m8s

Obviously, these lines do no appear on the regular version:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsDvSW8gQNI

How does the audience know its part? And where do the lyrics come from - is it official, or fan-created?

Comment: To be clear - I'm assuming this is a general practice, and not just for this song. Also, is there a way to embed videos, like on other SE sites?

Comment: I'm just going to assume it's like an audience at Rocky Horror knows to take toast... it starts small but after a while it spreads by osmosis, word of mouth.

Comment: By the sound of it, I have the feeling that there are only a few voices and not a whole crowd that sing. As @Tetsujin said, it could be fan made lines that only a few of them know. Anyway, I think it would be very hard to find an official source. I can suggest to find other live performances of this song to check if it happens in all places, or if it was just a one time occurrence.

Comment: And for now, [we can't embbed videos](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/3260).

Comment: I've heard this done with some English language songs.  "We Will Rock You" has [an unofficial call and response](http://playgroundjungle.com/2009/12/we-will-rock-you-parodies.html) line, and "[Mony Mony](http://ajournalofmusicalthings.com/where-did-the-special-lyrics-in-billy-idols-version-of-mony-mony-come-from/)" has an unprintable one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this answer is way late, but in case you're still wondering, that audience chanting/singing part is called the "fanchant". Kpop songs often have an official fanchant, usually taught to fans by the group releasing a video of themselves doing the fanchant along to the studio recording of the song. The video you linked to (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyL9LB6Z96Y) is exactly that.

Fanchants often start by reciting all of the group members' names at the beginning of the song (which might be a reason why in many kpop songs the first verse doesn't start immediately at the beginning of the song - perhaps it's because they want to leave room for the fanchant first. But that's just my speculation). After that, the fanchant usually involves repeating/echoing certain words in the song. Fanchants are just a fun way for the group and audience to connect by partaking in the song together.

Answer (score 2):

For a recent song, [Tulips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onqSAgAqpLQ), the band has released a video with "응원법", which Google translates to "Cheering" or "Support method". The video has playback of the song, and the band members are doing the audience's part:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyL9LB6Z96Y

So, at lease in this case, the answer is that there is official cheering, and it is released by the band.

Comment: That's kind of fun.  You might find this of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_and_response_(music)