# Unofficial Call and Response lyrics

Tags: lyrics, chart-success

Call and response is a common form for music around the world.  Typically the leader sings something, and the chorus or audience either repeats it back, or gives a set response. This is especially common in folk music, but there are also pop songs that include call-and-response style sections in the recorded versions.

However, [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6178/extra-audience-lyrics-in-a-k-pop-song) made me wonder about songs that have common responses that were never recorded.  I know of at least two, "[We Will Rock You](http://playgroundjungle.com/2009/12/we-will-rock-you-parodies.html)" and "[Mony Mony](http://ajournalofmusicalthings.com/where-did-the-special-lyrics-in-billy-idols-version-of-mony-mony-come-from/)".  Are there others?

To keep this from being too open-ended a list question: **What is the top-charting (US Billboard) song to have a commonly known set of extra lyrics that never appeared on an official recording?**  Bonus points if you can explain where those lyrics came from.